# Check if an element was created less than x seconds ago

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Problem**

I want to check if an element was created less than 60 seconds ago. Hence, using vue, the text should automatically turn from

*Is this text younger than 60 seconds?
true*

to

*Is this text younger than 60 seconds? false*

after 60 seconds.

However, it seems that either the `setTimeout` does not run at all or that `Date.now()` within the `setTimout` does not update. How can I solve this?

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  Is this text younger than 60 seconds?
  <br>
  {{ isNew }}
</div>
```

**js**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        isNew: false
  },
  methods: {
    checkIfIsNew() {
      let dateTimeToCheck = Date.parse("2021-11-03 18:16:00") // replace this hardcodeed datetime
      let seconds = (Date.now() - dateTimeToCheck) / 1000;
      console.log(seconds);
      if (seconds < 60) {
        this.isNew = true;
      } else {
        this.isNew = false;
      }
      if (this.isNew) {
        setTimeout(this.checkIfIsNew, 10*1000);
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.checkIfIsNew();
  },
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhr5y1dp/

Comment: Your example (with datetimeToCheck) worked for me just fine. Could you just add some debugging messages at the beginning of your code to ensure that `checkIfIsNew` is actually called in your code?

Comment: @raina77ow I added a `console.log(seconds)` which proves that the function is called. If you replace dateTimeToCheck with a value thats actually less than a minute older than `Date.now()` , you should see the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the code that you didn't post in your question, namely how do you set the `dateTimeToCheck`. I think you are setting this value less than a minute older than Date.now() on every invocation of `checkIfIsNew`. Instead you should set this value outside this function or to a constant value.

For example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7bzxkm2/) the `dateTimeToCheck` is set to creation time of the component in `data` and the code runs just fine.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        isNew: false,
        dateTimeToCheck: Date.now()
  },
  methods: {
    checkIfIsNew() {
        // let dateTimeToCheck = Date.parse("2021-11-03 18:16:00") // replace this hardcoded datetime
      let seconds = (Date.now() - this.dateTimeToCheck) / 1000;
      console.log(seconds);
      if (seconds < 60) {
        this.isNew = true;
      } else {
        this.isNew = false;
      }
      if (this.isNew) {
        setTimeout(this.checkIfIsNew, 10*1000);
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.checkIfIsNew();
  },
})
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for the clarification.